# Why am I getting 2 different IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I'm using AWS (EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, Load Balancer) for my site. Can I have CloudFlare configured to point to only 1 IP?

[image: CloudFlare]

Comment: You will need to use CNAME mapping for the elb A record. You can't map to a single IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a AWS ELB  you need to the point the Cloud Flare to the A_record of the ELB that is in use which is a Canonical name (C-Name) and not a IP address.